# How to retreive correct xml node through soapui

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui

I have an xml where I want putt out a 'RatePlanCode' from a `HotelOption` node, but the trick is that within the `HotelOption` node there needs to be a `HotelSupplement` 'Code'. If there is `HotelSupplement` 'Code' within then we don't take the 'RatePlanCode' for that hotel, only the ones that do. My question is how do I perform this check so that it takes out the correct 'RatePlanCode'?

Below is an xml example where you can see inbetween the first `HotelOption` there is no `HotelSupplement` 'Code' so we don't take that hotel's 'RatePlanCode' but the second `HotelOption` does have a `HotelSupplement` 'Code' so we take that 'RatePlanCode'.

```
<soap:Envelope>
   <soap:Body>
      <HotelAvailResponse>
         <AvailabilityRS TimeStamp="2017-02-08T17:07:17.3372275+00:00" IntCode="TLqw0EfFwMZFNlFLjsETG67d66mZhioSdJ4oCcM1Hao=">
            <Results>
               <HotelResult>
                  <HotelOptions>
                     <HotelOption RatePlanCode="xxxxxxxrEsM=" Status="OK" NonRefundable="false">
                        <AdditionalElements>
                           <HotelOffers>
                              <HotelOffer>
                                 <Description></Description>
                              </HotelOffer>
                           </HotelOffers>
                        </AdditionalElements>
                     </HotelOption>
                     <HotelOption RatePlanCode="xxxxxxxxxxGQjs=" Status="OK" NonRefundable="false">
                        <AdditionalElements>
                           <HotelSupplements>
                              <HotelSupplement Code="202964">
                                 <Name>Bed&amp;Breakfast</Name>
                              </HotelSupplement>
                           </HotelSupplements>
                           <HotelOffers>
                              <HotelOffer>
                                 <Description></Description>
                              </HotelOffer>
                           </HotelOffers>
                        </AdditionalElements>
                     </HotelOption>
                  </HotelOptions>
               </HotelResult>
            </Results>
         </AvailabilityRS>
      </HotelAvailResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Below is a working static version but it needs to be dynamic so that if there are more hotels in another example, we take one RatePlanCode that meets our criteria. This code gets stored in a property.

```
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
def response = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("GetHotelAvailability").getProperty("Response").getValue();
def xml = new XmlParser().parseText( response )

def RatePlanCode = xml.'soap:Body'.HotelAvailResponse[0].AvailabilityRS[0].Results[0].HotelResult[0].HotelOptions[0].HotelOption[1].@RatePlanCode

testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue('RatePlanCode', RatePlanCode)
```

Thank you

Comment: What if you do not have `HotelSupplement` in any `HotelOption`? or multiple HotelOption have HotelSupplement?

Comment: if no hotelsupplement in HotelOption then we don't take the rateplancode for that hoteloption. For multiple HotelOption have HotelSupplement, select a random rateplancode out of one of those HotelOptions. Actually can you provide two examples, one picking out random and one picking all of them and then I will decide later which one to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the groovy script:

- The script read the response from a step named "GetHotelAvailability".
- Looks for each HotelOption, and checks if there is an element called "HotelSupplement" and it has and attribute "Code" and gets RatePlanCode
- Result of "RatePlanCode" is list - it may have zero or many "RatePlanCode".
- If no rate plan code found in the list, then throws an assertion error. Otherwise, selects first element as "RatePlancde" and assigns into test case level custom property "RatePlanCode".

```groovy
def response = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("GetHotelAvailability").getProperty("Response").getValue()

def parsedxml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)
//Get the HotelOptions
def hOptions = parsedxml.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'HotelOption'}
//Get the rate plan codes
def getRatePlanCode = { option ->
    def res = option.'**'.findAll {it.name() == 'HotelSupplement' && it.@Code} 
    if (res)  return option.@RatePlanCode.text()   
    null
}

def planCodes = []
hOptions.each { if (getRatePlanCode(it)) planCodes << getRatePlanCode(it) }
log.info " plan codes : ${planCodes}"
//if no plan codes, then throw error
assert planCodes.size(), "No RatePlanCode present in the response"

//Assing rate plan code to test case custom property
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('RatePlanCode', planCodes[0].toString())
```